# Trying to save selected item on listbox in a single column in database

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am trying to save selected item on  listbox in a single column in database as comma separated.

```
<td>                
                <%--<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCertific" runat="server" class='form-control'></asp:DropDownList>--%>
                <asp:ListBox ID="ddlCertific" runat="server"  SelectionMode="Multiple">                                    
                </asp:ListBox>
            </td>
```

binding data on page load

```
void BindDropdown()
    {
        dt = conn.GetData("SELECT CODE_DESC as datac from code ");
        ddlCertific.DataSource = dt;
        ddlCertific.DataTextField = "datac";
        ddlCertific.DataValueField = "datac";

        ddlCertific.DataBind();
    }
```

Datasaving in database

```
protected void submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      string CERTIFIC;
CERTIFIC = ddlCertific.Text;
conn.IUD("INSERT INTO BAM(CERTIFIC) values ('"+ CERTIFIC +"')");
     }
```

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: any errors you're getting ? basically you want to send something from server side to client side. Is that what you asking in this question ?

Comment: @Prany i want the the no of items selected in listbox should be visible in client side as comma separated and those values should be stored in databse in a single column as comma separated like if is elected 5 values it will be seen as (1,2,3,4,5) in client side and in the same way it should be saved in database in one column only means it should be store in same way as it is visible in client side as comma separated in one column.

Comment: so in db currently these values are in seperate columns ?

Comment: no i want all to be store in same column as text eg. Like(1,2,3,4,5)

Comment: Did my answer serve your purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps after some research and it is working for me

1. Added listbox as per question

   ```
   <asp:ListBox ID="ddlCertific" runat="server"  SelectionMode="Multiple" Width="229px">
               <asp:ListItem Value="test1">test1</asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem Value="test2">test2</asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem Value="test3">test3</asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem Value="test4">test4</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:ListBox>
   ```
2. Added a hidden field - **Tricky part**

   ```
   <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="HiddenField1" ClientIDMode="Static" OnValueChanged="Date_ValueChanged" />
   ```
3. Javascript - This will add the selected items in the listbox using a ',' and do a post back since we need value at server

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function getSelectedOptions(sel) {
       var opts = [], opt;
       var a = [];

       // loop through options in select list
       for (var i=0, len=sel.options.length; i<len; i++) {
           opt = sel.options[i];

           // check if selected
           if ( opt.selected ) {
               // add to array of option elements to return from this function
               opts.push(opt);
               a.push(opt.value + ', '); 
          }
       }

       document.getElementById('HiddenField1').value = a.toString();
       // return array containing references to selected option elements
       return opts;
     }

    document.getElementById('ddlCertific').onchange = function (e)

   {
         getSelectedOptions(this);

         abc();
          //__doPostBack
     };

     function abc() {

         document.getElementById('HiddenField1').value;
           __doPostBack('HiddenField1'); 
     }

    </script>
   ```
4. Add client postback reference on server side and hiddenfield change event.

   ```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

       string val = ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this,"");
    }

     protected void Date_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       string value = HiddenField1.Value;
       //do your db stuffs
   }
   ```